# UnitOfWork exposed in service layer. Am i approaching this correctly?

Tags: c#, repository-pattern, unit-of-work, petapoco, service-layer

I am currently working on a commerce extension thing, where i am not able to use dependency injection, and i have to keep packages to a minimum.

I am using PetaPoco as a micro orm.

I created a unit of work, to handle disposal of dbcontext, and a factory to get my repositories.

I want to access methods in my repos in a straight forward way, without implementing any disposal logic in my services, since they might be used in non disposable classes/objects.

```cs
    public class OrderService : BaseService, IOrderService
    {
        public OrderService() : base(new UnitOfWorkProvider(), new 
        RepositoryFactory())
        {
        }

        public IEnumerable<CommerceOrder> GetAll()
        {
            using (var repo = 
                  RepositoryFactory.
                  CreateOrderRepositiory(UnitOfWorkProvider.GetUnitOfWork()))
            {
                  return repo.GetAll();
            }
         }
    }
```

All repositories implements IDisposable and takes care of calling dispose in UOW. This has been implemented in a Baserepo class.

**Repo factory**

```cs
    public class RepositoryFactory 
    {
            internal virtual OrderRepository CreateOrderRepositiory(IUnitOfWork unitOfWork)
            {
                return new OrderRepository(unitOfWork);
            }
    }
```

**Sample repo**

```cs
    public class OrderRepository : RepositoryBase<CommerceOrder>, 
    IOrderRepository<CommerceOrder>
    {
        public OrderRepository(IUnitOfWork unitOfWork)
            : base(unitOfWork)
        {
        }
    }
```

**Base repo**

```cs
    public class RepositoryBase<TEntity> : IRepository<TEntity>
    {

        #region IDisposable Support
        private bool disposedValue = false; // To detect redundant calls

        protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (!disposedValue)
            {
                if (disposing)
                {
                    UnitOfWork.Dispose();
                }

            disposedValue = true;
            }
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            Dispose(true);
        }
    }
```

**UnitOfWork**

```cs
 public class UnitOfWorkBase : IUnitOfWork
    {
        public UnitOfWorkBase(string connectionStringName, bool useTransaction)
        {
            Context = new Database(connectionStringName);
            _useDispose = true;
            if (!useTransaction) return;

            _transaction = new Transaction(Context);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// For use with other Database instances outside of Unit Of Work
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="context"></param>
        public UnitOfWorkBase(Database context)
        {
            Context = context;
            _useDispose = false;
        }

        public Database Context { get; private set; }
        private readonly bool _useDispose;
        private Transaction _transaction;

        public void Commit()
        {
            if (_transaction == null) return;

            _transaction.Complete();
            _transaction.Dispose();
            _transaction = null;
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            var doThrowTransactionException = false;

            if (_transaction != null)
            {
                Context.AbortTransaction();
                _transaction.Dispose();
                doThrowTransactionException = true;
            }

            if (_useDispose && Context != null)
            {
                Context.Dispose();
                Context = null;
            }

            if (doThrowTransactionException)
                throw new DataException("Transaction was aborted");
        }
    }
```

Should i expose repos in my unitofwork implementation, or is this approach ok?
I do not like the idea of the unitofwork implementation having that kind of responsibility.

Comment: I wrote an article for a while ago now, i think it may help.
It is not repositories responsibility to Dispose DBDontext as you do on your example

https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1157241/Very-Thin-Database-Layer-using-UnitOfWork-Pattern